# How to determine if locale currency has a decimal point

Tags: ios, objective-c, currency

Is there anyway in objective-c to determine if a currency uses a decimal point (regardless of declared NSNumber type)?

I have multiple locales and I use NSNumberFormatter (based on locale) to set string currency string style, however  before-hand I would like to know if the selected locale currency uses a decimal point.

```
[_cf setLocale:
[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIndentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locale]]]];
[cf setNumberStyle:NSNUmberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *value = [cf stringFromNumber:price];
return value;
```

Comment: You mean a decimal point as opposed to a comma (which is a matter of locale, not currency), or a decimal point as opposed to currencies that do not customarily use decimals (e.g. JPY)?

Comment: correct. based on selected locale, I would like to know if a decimal (or comma which in some locales act like a decimal)

Comment: The term you want is "Decimal separator". That allows for different characters that serve that purpose (As jcaron pointed out in his comment comma is another common decimal separator.) Are you looking to see if a locale uses ANY decimal separator (YES or NO) are you trying to figure out if it specifically uses a period, or are you looking to get the decimal separator character, whatever it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After creating the `NSNumberFormatter` with currency style, ask the formatter how many fraction digits it has.

```
NSInteger maxFractionDigits = cf.maximumFractionDigits;
if (maxFractionDigits == 0) {
    // this currency is an integer, not a decimal
}
```

One example where this is true is the Japanese Yen (`¥`).